# Why is map.put not maintaining the ordering of keys

Tags: java, dictionary

I have defined a dictionary :

> `Map<String, Integer>`

Then in the code, I am adding entries to the collection :

```
map.put("> 80", // some stream() + lambda based logic for calculating the value part);
map.put("60 - 80", ....);
map.put("40 - 60", ....);
map.put("20 - 40", ....);
map.put(" < 40", ....);
```

Later in the debug mode, I see that the ordering of the keys have changed. For e.g. "20 -40" is first, "60- 80" is last. Why is the ordering of keys changing? How can I maintain the ordering of keys in the collection.

Comment: HashMap does not guarantee ordering of keys. If you want to maintain the order of input, use LinkedHashMap

Comment: You may want to create a new class let's say `Range` which is comparable, and have a `TreeMap<Range, Integer>`. It could be more suited for what you need than the traditional answer "use `LinkedHashMap` to maintain insertion order when iterating".

Comment: The javadoc for HashMap states "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.
"

Answer (score 4):

If you want the ordering of the keys to be maintained you should use a `LinkedHashMap` which, by default, iterates over the keys according to their insertion order.